# SharePoint Online - Show Confirmation Popup Upon Initial Login

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'd like to show a confirmation popup to a user when they first login to a SharePoint Online site. They should be able to see the confirmation text and be able to click, "I Agree" or "Cancel". If I Agree is clicked then the user can proceed but if Cancel is clicked then the user is logged out.

When the user clicks I Agree the user wont see the popup message again until their next session.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.